# Python automation: file manager

Tags: python

I create a script to auto-sort my download directory. Basically I want this to run on background, sort every file I download and move it in the correct folder.

The issue is that when the script is running, the download always fails. I think this might be because when chrome starts the download, it creates a temporary file. And only show the entire file when the download is done. I have added the condition to exclude 'crdownload' files. But still, when I try to download files, it goes until the end and fails.

How can I solve this?

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/python2.7

# pip install watchdog fro theses package to work
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

import os
import json
import time
import datetime

ROOT_DIR = '/home/xxx/Downloads/'
assertMsg = ''' File \'%s\' don\'t exists. Abord ... ''' % (ROOT_DIR)

# make sure directory exists before starting the application
assert os.path.exists(ROOT_DIR), assertMsg
# + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S_")


# /home/xxx/Downloads

# chrome Unconfirmed 332952.crdownload


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
  def on_modified(self, event):
    today_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(ROOT_DIR) if os.path.isfile(ROOT_DIR + f)]
    for filename in files:
      name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename) # get file extention
      if ext == 'crdownload':
        continue
      if not ext:
        ext = 'others'
      ext = ext.strip('.')
      ext = ext.lower()

      source_file = ROOT_DIR + filename
      new_destination = ROOT_DIR + ext +  "/" + today_date + "/" + filename

      if not os.path.exists(ROOT_DIR + ext):
        os.mkdir(ROOT_DIR + ext)
        os.mkdir(ROOT_DIR + ext + "/" + today_date)
      else:
        if not  os.path.exists(ROOT_DIR + ext + "/" + today_date):
          os.mkdir(ROOT_DIR + ext + "/" + today_date)

      os.rename(source_file, new_destination)

folder_to_track = ROOT_DIR
folder_destination = ROOT_DIR

event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(60)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  observer.stop()
observer.join()

observer.join()
```

Downloads fail:
[image]

Comment: Why it fails? Do you get an exception? Did you try to download something and test with the debugger to see step-by-step the process?

Comment: What do you mean by not working as expected?

Comment: @KostasCharitidis download fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I reproduced and found out what is happening. Actually your `if ext == 'crdownload':` is never met. You should either change that to

```
if ext == '.crdownload':
```

or change this :

```
name, ext = filename.split('.')
```

You were checking if `ext` was equal to `crdownload` but your `ext` was `.crdownload`. You should have imagined that while your script was creating a folder named `crdownload` meaning it didn't pass this step.